# Looping though an array, taking a subset at each iteration and store into list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I'm reading strings from a text file into an `string[]`. The text file has data in sequence, for example, the *first* `7` elements are considered to be *one record*, and the *next* `7` elements are considered a *second record*, etc.

I need to store these records in objects, so at the end I will have a list of objects (`List<Settlement>`).

I have looked for solutions which suggest using **LINQ**, but I have no background in it.

Here is a sample file

```cs
public static List<Settlement> ReadFromLogFile()
{
    string filename = path + @"\BM_DB_MIGRATION.txt";
    List<Settlement> settlements = new List<Settlement>();

    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

        // Reading 7 elements from lines into an object of Settelment at each iteration 
        // and store the object in a list of objects...
    }

    return settlements;
}
```

Comment: sorry. I mean an array. I'll edit my question

Comment: What defines an "element"? Or, put another way, what delimits each data point in your text file?

Comment: An element is a simple string at each line. I'll add a sample file

Comment: We can understand what you are trying to achieve better if you can provide us the content of `BM_DB_MIGRATION.txt` and structure of `Settlement` .

Comment: [The MoreLinq "Batch" function](https://markheath.net/post/exploring-morelinq-7-batching) looks suitable for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you are looking for `GroupBy` (Linq):

```
line #0 - group #0 
line #1 - group #0 
...
line #6 - group #0
line #7 - group #1
...
line #13 - group #1
line #14 - group #2
...
```

**Code:**

```
   using System.IO; 
   using System.Linq;
   ...

   public static List<Settlement> ReadFromLogFile() {
     string filename = Path.Combine(path, @"BM_DB_MIGRATION.txt");

     if (File.Exists(filename)) {
       return File
         .ReadLines(filename)
         .Select((line, index) => new {
            line,
            index
          }) 
         .GroupBy(item => item.index / 7, // group of [0..6] lines, then [7..13] lines etc. 
                  item => item.line)
         .Select(group => group.ToArray()) // Let's optimize group items access
         .Select(group => new Settlement( // turn 7 lines into Settlement
            //TODO: put the right Settlement constructor's syntax here
            group.ElementAtOrDefault(0),  // ...OrDefault - null, if line doesn't exist  
            group.ElementAtOrDefault(1),
            group.ElementAtOrDefault(2), 
            group.ElementAtOrDefault(3),  
            group.ElementAtOrDefault(4),
            group.ElementAtOrDefault(5), 
            group.ElementAtOrDefault(6)  
          ))
         .ToList();  
     }

     return new List<Settlement>(); 
   }
```

Comment: Note that each call to `group.ElementAtOrDefault(N)` will iterate over N elements of the group (since group will be of type `GroupedEnumerable` so the optimisation of using it as an `IList` cannot be made). This makes the code above extremely inefficient since it will be iterating over the input multiple times. For this reason, the MoreLinq "`Batch()`" method is much better.

Comment: @Matthew Watson: Thank you! Agree, an optimization for `ElementAt` is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

An example without LINQ:

```
public static List<Settlement> ReadFromLogFile()
{
    string filename = path + @"\BM_DB_MIGRATION.txt";
    List<Settlement> settlements = new List<Settlement>();

    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

        // Reading 7 elements from lines into an object of Settelment at each iteration 
        // and store the object in a list of objects...
        var record = new List<string>(7);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (record.Count == 7)
            {
                // convert the lines to the Settlement data structure
                var s = new Settlement(record);
                settlements.Add(s);
                record.Clear();
            }

            record.Add(line);
        }
    }

    return settlements;
}
```

Comment: I believe OP means that every 7 rows in the file is 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the constructor of your Settlement class takes an array of strings, this uses the [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) and [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) LINQ methods to read 7 lines at a time, while iterating through the lines you've read from the file:

```
public static List<Settlement> ReadFromLogFile()
{
    string filename = path + @"\BM_DB_MIGRATION.txt";
    List<Settlement> settlements = new List<Settlement>();

    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

        // Reading 7 elements from lines into an object of Settelment at each iteration 
        // and store the object in a list of objects...

        for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 7)
        {
            var obj = lines.Skip(i).Take(7).ToArray();
            var settlement = new Settlement(obj);

            settlements.Add(settlement);
        }
    }

    return settlements;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without loading all of the file into memory, and without having to iterate multiple times.

To do this, you could use the MoreLinq Batch operator [which is available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.Batch/).

Alternatively, you can just use the implementation below:

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public sealed class Batch<T>
    {
        public readonly int            Index;
        public readonly IEnumerable<T> Items;

        public Batch(int index, IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            Index = index;
            Items = items;
        }
    }

    // Note: Not threadsafe, so not suitable for use with Parallel.Foreach() or IEnumerable.AsParallel()

    public static IEnumerable<Batch<T>> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int batchSize)
    {
        var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
        int index      = 0;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield return new Batch<T>(index++, nextBatch(enumerator, batchSize));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> nextBatch<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int blockSize)
    {
        do { yield return enumerator.Current; }
        while (--blockSize > 0 && enumerator.MoveNext());
    }
}
```

This implementation has the advantage of not storing interim results in an array, but it has the disadvantage that is is not threadsafe.

Anyway, given that or the MoreLinq version, you can address your problem by using it to batch the file into arrays of seven lines like so:

```
if (File.Exists(filename))
{
    var batchesOf7Lines = 
        File.ReadLines(filename)
       .Partition(batchSize:7)
       .Select(batch => batch.Items.ToArray());

    foreach (var batch in batchesOf7Lines)
    {
        // batch[] is an array of 7 strings (or less if the file is NOT a multiple of 7 lines!)
        // Do something with batch[].
    }
}
```

This does not keep a copy of the entire file in memory, and it makes only a single pass through the file. It does create an array of 7 strings for each batch, but even that can be avoided if your consumer accepts an `IEnumerable<string>`.